# Import test module into main test - Nightwatch

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm learning Nightwatch and have successfully got my first tests running. I'd now like to organise my tests a little better and use have a bunch of reusable common tests that I can build a main test with going forward. I've attempted to set this up using the code below but I'm not too familiar with Node exports, (truth be known I would prefer to use es6 import / export so if anyone can shed any light on this I'd be grateful) so I've probably made some fundamental error:

File structure

```
Tests
 -auth
  -- auth.js
 index.js
```

nightwatch.json

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },
  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mostesting",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test-e2e": "nightwatch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.19",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const auth = require('./auth/auth.js')

module.exports = {
  'Log into system': auth.login()
}
```

auth.js

```
exports.login = function (client) {
  client
    .url('http://myurl.co.uk')
    .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
    .assert.title('Reach - Log in')
    .assert.visible('#UserName')
    .setValue('#UserName', 'XXXX')
    .assert.visible('#Password')
    .setValue('#Password', 'XXXX')
    .assert.visible('input[value="Login"]')
    .click('input[value="Login"]')
    .waitForElementVisible('img.test', 10000, false)
}
```

When I run the test it opens, it runs and passes but at the end I get the following console error:

```
OK. 6 assertions passed. (8.549s)

There was an error while starting the test runner:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at Object.exports.login (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mostesting/tests/auth/auth.js:3:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mostesting/tests/index.js:4:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at new Module (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mostesting/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/module.js:7:23)
```

Please can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `exports.login = function (client) {` from `auth.js` is expecting the `client` argument which is not provided by the call `auth.login()` in `index.js`.

Comment: Regarding structuring, nightiwatch provides a page object api
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're defining your test run, no need to call test run function `auth.login()`. What you need is to export this function, so Nightwatch can execute it:

```
// index.js

const auth = require('./auth/auth.js')

module.exports = {
    'Log into system': auth.login
}
```